# How to print data in URL by PHP

Tags: php, url

"https://www.bryllupfoto.com/variable/key.php/?ck=559"

I would like the echo function on my PHP page to print the information in the URL. in this case 559.

(I don't know if the syntax in my url is correct)

Comment: `key.php/?ck=559` is wrong; remove the `/` here. The slash implies going to the root.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner But that should not cause any problems in the request.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yes it will since PHP considers `key.php` as being a folder, *theoretically*.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for the info :-)

Comment: welcome @Aniket

Comment: The slash is a red herring here.  It likely depends on the server environment as to what the behaviour is.  Also the question as it stands is quite ambiguous.

Comment: @Tomas, welcome, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL:

```
https://www.bryllupfoto.com/variable/key.php?ck=559
```

Your php:

```
echo $_GET['ck'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Access you url value using thier key and echo it
echo     $_GET[`ck`] ;